# Laravel Webpack Module parse failed

Tags: laravel, webpack

I have started to use Laravel 8 and I have just noticed a error coming from Webpack:

> Uncaught Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)

I have read from various posts that this is caused by by webpack and vue. I am not using Vue directly, but I am using Laravel auth UI, which I can assume uses Vue. Fixes for the error from what I have researched suggest adding .vue() to the app.js reference in webpack.mix.js. I have tested this fix:

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js').vue()
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .sourceMaps();
```

The error persists, despite an update to node to current stable version.

The Laravel app is pretty basic, I am not compiling anything and purely coding locally on MAMP. The webpack documentation around the error is not particularly helpful in this instance. Any direction would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Within a few minutes of posting the question I solved the issue. The webpack.mix.js file update was working, but I had failed to run 'npm run dev' after this update. Anyone facing the same error should ensure they add .vue() to the webpack file and then run 'npm run dev'